# Collision between a sprite and a tilemap with Cocos2d and Box2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I have the following map I made in Tiled, and then added to my project:

```
map = [[CCTMXTiledMap alloc] initWithTMXFile:@"FirstLevel.tmx"];
[self addChild:map];
```

I also have the following object which contains the player that I can move around:

```
objectLayer = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"level.pvr.ccz" capacity:150];
[self addChild:objectLayer z:10];

player = [[[Player alloc] initWithGameLayer:self] autorelease];
  [objectLayer addChild:[player ccNode] z:10000];
  [player setPhysicsPosition:b2Vec2FromCC(240,150)];
```

I can see my tilemap in the background, but it doesn't collide with anything. How can I make Player colide with the layers in my Tilemap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it with Rubymotion and Joybox http://joybox.io/